# Powershell Get-Service report wrong information

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-remoting

I've created a powershell script to list all domain controllers under current trusted forest, and than check each individual server for specific services if it's running or not and send an email with report.

I found 2 issues so far.

1. `Get-Service -name "MyService" -ComputerName $myComputer` "will say no service is found with that name, but if I list all the services : `Get-Service  -ComputerName $myComputer it will say "This operation might require other privileges."` This is a problem because I'm reporting that the service doesn't exist but it is actually there.
2. For some reason if I just run the powershell script from command line manually it lists way more servers and most of the info is correct. But I schedule the powershell script from windows task manager with that same account the information is all wrong and it reports way less servers.

Script:

```
#$domain = [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain]::GetCurrentDomain().Name
#$numerOfDomainControlers= nslookup $domain
Clear-Content .\log.txt

$startTime = Get-Date

$allDCs = ((Get-ADForest).Domains | %{ Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $_ } | Where-Object { $_.hostname -notlike '*root*' }).hostname


foreach( $allDC in $allDCs){



$testConnection = Test-Connection $allDC -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Write-Host 

if($testConnection -like "true") {

    $SyncStatus = Get-Service -name "MyServicesName" -ComputerName $allDC  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 


    if($SyncStatus.length -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "MyServicesName doesn't exists on:"$allDC 

    $SyncStatus = "MyServicesName doesn't exists on:" + $allDC 
    $logs = $SyncStatus |Out-File .\log.txt -Append
                                         }
                                            else{
                                                write-host "MyServicesName on "$allDC "is: " $SyncStatus.status
                                                $SyncStatus = "MyServicesName on " + $allDC + "is: " + $SyncStatus.status
                                                 $logs = $SyncStatus |Out-File .\log.txt -Append
                                                }

                                    }
                                    else 
                                    {
                                    Write-Host "Test Connection to Server failed:"$allDC 
                                    $SyncStatus = "Test Connection to Server failed:" + $allDC 
                                    $logs = $SyncStatus |Out-File .\log.txt -Append
                                    }


}


$endTime = Get-Date
$totalTime =  New-TimeSpan -start $startTime -end $endTime
Write-Host $totalTime
$logs = "Total Time in Seconds:" + $totalTime |Out-File .\log.txt -Append
                                                                #send Email

                                                                $logs = Get-Content .\log.txt
                                                                $serverName = $env:computername
                                                                $LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                                                                $FromAddress = "email.com"
                                                                $ToAddress = "email.com"                                                                
                                                                foreach($log in $logs)
                                                                {
                                                                $Messagebody = $messagebody + $log + "`r`n" |Out-String
                                                                }
                                                                [string] $MessageSubject ="Status Report runing on " + $serverName +"  " + $endTime
                                                                $SendingServer = "server"
                                                                Send-MailMessage -to $ToAddress  -from $FromAddress -subject $MessageSubject -smtpServer  $SendingServer -body $Messagebody -Attachments .\log.txt
```

Comment: [1] using `$allDC` for just one DC is deeply confusing. you would likely do better with just `$DC`. [*grin*] [2] the `Test-Connection` cmdlet with the `-Quiet` parameter will return `$False/$True`, so there is no need for `-ErrorAction` in that case. [3] `$testConnection` will contain a _boolean_, not a _string_. your test is for `-like 'true'` [a string] instead of for a boolean. [4] the `-like` operator is a _wildcard operator_ and you are not using any wildcard. that means the test is essentially the same as using `-eq`. //// **_try fixing items 3 & 4._**

Comment: Hi Lee, Thanks for the comets. I will make the changes but that's not going to fix  the main problems I've described.

Comment: Hi @Theo , would you be able to help with this issue. Thank you

Comment: [1] you still have >>> `if($testConnection -like "true") {` <<< in your code. that _MAY_ cause odd problems since you are comparing a `[bool]` to a `[string]`. it should work as is, tho. ///// [2] your code indentation is so very random that it is quite difficult to read. when you post your updated code, please format it so that it does NOT have the current nearly random indentation.

Comment: Hi @ Lee_Dailey. I found the issue. Its something to do with PowerShell. The check you mention does't  make any difference I got the same results weather I use like or a value. The problem is Checking for access with : Get-Service -ComputerName $DC -ErrorVariable foundError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue , if I had the service name in there in returns wrong information. So now I check if I have access first before I check if the service is running.  Everything work as expected. I know code is not up to standard I'm in no way powershell developer etc. Thanks

Comment: you are most welcome ... glad to kinda-sorta help. thank you for letting me know what the real problem was - and the fix! [*grin*]

Comment: No problem Cheers.